# PHP redirect function from /beer to /?search=beer

Tags: url, redirect, web

thanks for reading my question.

I want to add this function in my website:

When the visitor type in the address bar this:

zicher.mx/beer

automaticaly redirect to: this url:

https://zicher.mx/index.php?buscar=beer

is it posible?

Please apologize my English and thanks in advance.

I don't know how exactly I need to search in google or stackoverflow to find this redirection feature.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a permanent solution, but you can send something like this to make the client redirect to a new page (btw it's untested):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://zicher.mx/index.php?buscar=<?php echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; ?>" />
<script>
var x = document.createElement("p");
x.innerHTML = 'Click <a href="https://zicher.mx/index.php?buscar=<?php echo $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; ?>">here</a> to search for ' + location.href.replace("zicher.mx/", "") + ".";
document.body.appendChild(x);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and tell you what happened.